# how to fix Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors

I have tried everything I can think of. I removed almost everything from my document to give it the most simplest of entries, and I STILL get this error message. What am I doing wrong? How can fix this so that I may see my document in a pdf? See below my MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}{options} 
\pagestyle{headings} 
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\begin{document} 
\input{./title.tex} 
\section{Introduction} 
\label{sec:intro) 
\subsection 
\subsubsection 
\subsubsection 
\subsubsection 
\subsubsubsection 
\subsection 
\subsubsection 
\subsubsection 
\subsubsection 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without the actual code, there's little we can do. Please reduce your document to a minimal, complete version reproducing the problem and added to your question.

Comment: \documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}{options}
\pagestyle{headings}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}
\input{./title.tex}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro)
\subsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsubsection
\subsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\end{document}

Comment: With the above, I get the error:   sample.tex(2): Error: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: But each `\section` or subsection must carry an argument, right? Like: `\section{test}`. What is the `{options}` part for?

Comment: By argument, do you mean additional text? I have reduced my original document (i.e., removed the text) and provided just the basics. I get the error with either presentation.

Comment: I think its the label part: It should be `\label{sec:intro}` and you have `\label{sec:intro)`

Comment: `\subsubsubsection` is undefined as well.

Answer (score 5):

There are several errors in the code. There's no need to use the option `pdftex`; also, there's a typo in `\label`; you have

```
\label{sec:intro)
```

but it should be

```
\label{sec:intro}
```

(you had a closing parenthesis instead of the closing brace). `\subsection` needs an argument and there's no `\subsubsubsection` command. Also, you are loading the `graphicx` package like this:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}{options}
```

and the right way is

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Try this; assuming your bibliographical database is `bibfile.bib` and that it is in the same directory as the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\pagestyle{headings} 

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro} 
\subsection{test}
\cite{<key>}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

where `<key>` is the key used for one of the bibliographical entries of `bibfile.bib`.

Comment: did that and inserted text back in. Text without citations, it worked. Text with citations, I get the same error. How do you add both in-text citations. For in text, do you use {\cite [label]} and then do you add to the preamble, like {\usepackage}{natbib}. Must you add to the end of the document, too, such as {\bibliography}{bibfile} and {\bibliography}{plainnat}? Thanks

Comment: @Keith you need to do some reading; see this [`LaTeX wikibook`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), specifically the bibliography sections 5.3 and 5.4. Additional problems might be better treated in new questions. Also, don't forget to accept the answer that you consider best solves your problem (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).)

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}{natbib}
\pagestyle{headings}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\subsection 
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsubsection
\subsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection
\subsubsection

{\bibliography}{plainnat}

{\bibliography}{bibfile}

\end{document}

Comment: I get the same latex error, missing: \begin{document} when including bibliography.

Comment: @Keith please see my updated answer.

Comment: Error: LaTeX Error: File `natbib.sty' not found.

Comment: @Keith you need to install a complete LaTeX system. In the meantime, you can work without `natbib`: delete the line `\usepackage{natbib}` and change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.

Comment: Where the in text citation should be, I get a [?] in pdf.

Comment: @Keith please read some basic documentation as I suggested before. You need to process your document using `pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex`.

Comment: latex latex_source_code.tex
bibtex latex_source_code.aux
latex latex_source_code.tex
latex latex_source_code.tex

Comment: It says to type these into the command line but, I do not know where that is?

Comment: @Keith it's a terminal or console. Your editor probably has the functionality to do that so you don't have to use the command line.

Comment: i click pdflatex, then bibtex, then pdflatex, pdflatex, and then pdf...I still see [?] where the in text citations should be.

Comment: @Keith make sure that the argument of `\cite` exactly matches the key used for one of the entries in the .bib database.

Comment: I'm looking at the top line of each entry...so @article{<ref,I'd include \cite{<ref,  is that correct?

Comment: @Keith yes, if you have something like `@article{xyz,...}` then you use `\cite{xyz}` in your document.

Comment: They're the same, but I am now prompted that two of the references are undefined on inputs lines 15 and 16.

Comment: @Keith Open a new question with the code.